# Resolving 504 Gateway Timeout and Proxy Errors in Different Configurations

Tags: django, apache, reverse-proxy

I am facing a challenge with different error behaviors under two server configurations. When operating on localhost or without a reverse proxy, a 504 Gateway Timeout error is displayed in the Network tab of the browser's developer tools, which is expected in my setup.

However, when using a reverse proxy, users are directly presented with a "Proxy error" message in the browser window. This issue persists across different pages, including https://[sample-ip-address]:8005/marketplace, adversely affecting the user experience.

Here are two relevant log entries that may shed light on the issue:

Docker Logs:

```
2023-11-17T15:14:19.339905242Z requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='[sample-ip-address]', port=9440): Max retries exceeded with url: /PrismGateway/services/rest/v1/vms/[unique-id]/stats?metrics=controller_user_bytes&intervalInSecs=60&startTimeInUsecs=[start-time]&endTimeInUsecs=[end-time] (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object>, 'Connection to [sample-ip-address] timed out. (connect timeout=None)'))
```

Apache Error Logs

```
[Fri Nov 17 07:11:42.599031 2023] [proxy:error] [pid 25219:tid 140437838784256] [remote [sample-ip-address]:53152] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /users/vm_listing/HVDs,
```

I am looking for insights into why these different error behaviors are occurring with and without a reverse proxy and how I can resolve the proxy error issue to enhance user experience.
I am using Docker, Django and Apache Reverse Proxy

Also, for clear understanding, here is my flow:

Without Reverse Proxy:

1. Users go to the dashboard page.
2. The dashboard page loads. The Network tab shows a 502 error (which is expected).
3. At this moment, when users click on any other page, it loads the page without any issues.

With Apache Reverse Proxy:

1. Users go to the dashboard page.
2. The dashboard page loads.
3. At this moment, when users click on any other page, it takes some time, and then the following error shows: "Proxy Error - The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server. The proxy server could not handle the request. Reason: Error reading from the remote server."